# why apache2 server is not processing below php file

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu

OS: Ubuntu, Apache2, mysql-server

I hosted one index.html on localhost in Apache2 server with one dc.php file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" name="form1" action="dc.php">
    Username <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
    Password <input type="text" name="password" id="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<form method="post" name="form2" action="cancel.html">
</body>
```

and here is code for dc.php file

```
  <?php
session_start();

ob_start();


$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$mysqlPassword="mypass#"; // Mysql pass

$db_name="mydb1"; // Database name
$tbl_name="mytbl1"; // Table name


mysql_connect("$host", "$username","$mysqlPassword")or die("Cannot connect to MySQL database.");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("MySQL database unavailable.");

$password=$_POST['username'];
$confirm=$_POST['password'];

if ($password != $confirm) {
header("location:error.html");
break;
}


mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytbl1(password, confirm) VALUES('$password', '$confirm');");

echo "Updating records... $password";

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

so when i clicking on submit button instead of executing php file, the browser stops with url

```
http://localhost/dc.php
```

with blank page, and the values are not inserted in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your action of form is dc.php so if you submit your form  the page goes to dc.php , your problem because an error occurred in your code you can add this lines to first of your code to see what excatly make error [in dc.php]

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: now it's showing Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/t/t/dc.php on line 21

Comment: you should use mysqli_connect instead,beacause mysql_* deprecated in newer version of php , your php version of your local enviroment is older than your remote server

Comment: and its better to use mysqli functions my friend google for mysqli functions and how to use it